# How to get the coordinates of an object in a tkinter canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter

I can't seem to figure out how to retrieve the `x,y` position of an oval created on a Tkinter canvas using Python via

```
c.create_oval(x0, y0, x1, y2)
```

I understand that `Tkinter` creates the oval inside the box specified by `x0,y0,x1,y2` and if I can get those coordinates that would also work.

I need the coordinates to move the oval by an offset equal to the mouse coords and the actual oval.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Assign the results of `c.create_oval` to `x` -- that's the "object ID" of the oval.  Then,

```
c.coords(x)
```

gives you the `(x1, y1, x2, y2)` tuple of the oval's coordinates (you call `coords` with new coordinates following the `x` to move the oval).