# ball movement with classes and tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the following code which manages to make a ball bounce on the top and bottom ends of the screen.

**Working code for bouncing on top and bottom**

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time

class Ball: 
    def __init__(self,canvas,color): 
        self.canvas=canvas 
        self.id=canvas.create_oval(30,30,50,50,fill=color) 
        self.canvas.move(self.id,100,200)

        #ADD THESE LINES TO OUR __INIT__ METHOD
        self.x=0 
        self.y=-1 
        self.canvas_height=self.canvas.winfo_height() 

    def draw(self): 
        self.canvas.move(self.id,self.x,self.y) 
        pos=self.canvas.coords(self.id) 

        if pos[1] <=0:
            self.y=1
        if pos[3] >=self.canvas_height: 
            self.y=-1


def main():
    tk=Tk()
    tk.title("My 21st Century Pong Game")
    tk.resizable(0,0)
    tk.wm_attributes("-topmost",1)
    canvas=Canvas(tk,bg="white",width=500,height=400,bd=0,highlightthickness=0)
    canvas.pack()
    tk.update()

    ball1=Ball(canvas,'green')
    while 1:
        tk.update()
        ball1.draw() #call the ball draw method here
        time.sleep(0.01)
main()
```

When trying to make it happen for left to right (bounce on the left and right wall), I cannot quite figure out the logic or solve my error as seen below.

**What I've tried for bouncing on left and right**

```
  self.x=1 #set the object variable x to 0 (don't move the ball horizontally)
        self.y=-0 #set the object variable y to -1 (this means keep moving the ball UP on initilisation)
        self.canvas_height=self.canvas.winfo_height() #set the canvas height by calling the canvas function winfo_height (it gives us the current canvas height)

    def draw(self): 
        self.canvas.move(self.id,self.x,self.y) 
        pos=self.canvas.coords(self.id) 

        if pos[2] <=0: #if you hit the top of the screen then stop subtracting 1 as defined in the __init__ method and therefore stop moving up -reverse directions
            self.x=-1
        if pos[3] >=self.canvas_height: #if the bottom coordinates are greater or equal to canvas height, then reverse again, and set y back to -1 (go up)
            self.x=1
```

**For an answer**,

could someone provide a **simple explanation** as to the logic that is needed to solve the problem,where the coordinates are coming from and what pos[0],pos[1] etc refer to. I have an idea, but it is not at all clear and would benefit (as would SO I imagine) from some clarity.

So, I'm after an explanation + coded solution fix (using my original code) to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The code is almost right. In fact, it's so almost right that a moment's further thought would probably have given you the answer. Your 'move x' code has been copy-pasted from the 'move y' code, but not changed enough. Beware of doing this.

In response to 'what do pos[0] etc mean', I invite you to read [Get coords of an oval in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679418/get-coords-of-an-oval-in-tkinter).
Usually, coordinates of a rectangle are given as (left, top, right, bottom).

You'll notice that I've changed some things below, besides correcting your errors:

1. I've changed the `x` & `y` variables to `vx` and `vy`. The values are the velocities of the ball, not the position.
2. The function name is now `move`, not `draw`, since the function moves and doesn't draw.
3. The `alive` variable with the `tk.protocol` line gives the program a tidy way of cleaning up after the user closes the window.

.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time

class Ball: 
    def __init__(self,canvas,color):
        self.alive = True
        self.canvas = canvas 
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(30, 30, 50, 50, fill=color) 
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 100, 200)

        #ADD THESE LINES TO OUR __INIT__ METHOD
        self.vx = 1 
        self.vy = -1 
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width() 
        self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height() 

    def move(self): 
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.vx, self.vy) 
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id) 
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.vx = 1
        if pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.vx = -1
        if pos[1] <= 0:
            self.vy = 1
        if pos[3] >= self.canvas_height: 
            self.vy = -1

    def kill(self):
        self.alive = False

def main():
    tk = Tk()
    tk.title("My 21st Century Pong Game")
    tk.resizable(0, 0)
    tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
    canvas = Canvas(tk, bg="white", width=500, height=400, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
    canvas.pack()
    tk.update()

    tk.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: ball1.kill())

    ball1 = Ball(canvas, 'green')
    while ball1.alive:
        tk.update()
        ball1.move() #call the ball move method here
        time.sleep(0.01)
    tk.destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```